# How to update Google's Datalab to the latest version?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to use the new --subnet parameter. 
I've used `gcloud components update`, but using `datalab create --subnet` ... keeps me returning "unknow method"...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`$ gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/) will update all the components you have to their latest version.

I think you are getting "datalab: error: unrecognized arguments" error is because `--subnet` is not yet one of the [options for create command](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create).
In the last comment of [adding subnet flag feature request](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/pull/2015)  says:

> This change has been submitted, but is not yet included in a Cloud SDK release.
>
> If you want to use it before it gets included in a Cloud SDK release, then clone this repository and run the python code from your locally cloned repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab.git
cd datalab
./tools/cli/datalab.py create --subnet ...
```